# Отправка файла в Blob format

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob

Где нужно указывать тип файла (например: .png,.pdf, ...) при отправке файла в формате blob ?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте экземпляр `File` из `Blob`. В конструкторе укажите имя и тип файла:

```
var blob = yourBlob;
var file = new File([blob], 'myfile.pdf, {type: 'application/pdf'});
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('myFile', file);

$.post( "test.php", formData );
```